# Designing a single table with different columns that enforce uniqueness

Tags: postgresql

I need some advice on how to design this table, along with setting up indexes on the table to make sure lookups are fast.

I have a table that contains a user contact like:

```
users_contact
- id
- email
- home_phone
- cell
```

**The user only needs to enter 1 of: email, home_phone, cell.**

I will need to query the table, looking up by either email, home_phone or cell.

1. How should I index this table, I was thinking of 3 indexes, where I only have the index when:

   email is NOT NULL

   home_phone is NOT NULL

   cell is NOT NULL
2. Would it be better to create another column like: "lookup_key", and just store that value in this column and then have a type column that tells me what the value is?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would go third option - function based index instead - if you use same in where when you select the index will be consumed.

Comment: Add another column, which is concat of email, home_phone and cell filled by BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE trigger. Index it, require NOT NULL and use for lookup.

Comment: @iTollu I hate triggers :)

Comment: @Blankman Then you could store JSON or XML, containing any of those three fields. It could be validated either by backend, or by schema, if your DB supports. Indexes for semistructured data can also be supported (e. g. Postgres, XML)

Comment: @Blankman Anyway, validation of business rules ("only one of three values is required") looks more like business logic than data consistensy logic - consequently, it'd better be implemented in a backend.

Answer (score 0):

I would try 3rd option - index on coalesce of three fields:

```
t=# create table users_contact (id bigint, email text, phone text, cell text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into users_contact (email) select '1';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into users_contact (email) select '2';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into users_contact (cell) select '3';
INSERT 0 1
t=# create index i1 on users_contact (coalesce(email,phone,cell));
CREATE INDEX
t=# with a as (select generate_series(1,10000,1) g) insert into users_contact(phone) select g from a;
INSERT 0 10000
t=# explain select * from users_contact where coalesce(email,phone,cell) = '1';
                                QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using i1 on users_contact  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=104)
   Index Cond: (COALESCE(email, phone, cell) = '1'::text)
(2 rows)

t=# explain select * from users_contact where cell = '1';
                           QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on users_contact  (cost=0.00..46.69 rows=1 width=104)
   Filter: (cell = '1'::text)
(2 rows)
```

Comment: and this works fine if someone enters email and phone? i.e multiple column values.  Email, home_phone, cell all have to be unique.

Comment: coalesce returns first not null argument. so if you have some priority, it will work. But I suggested it thinking you will have only of three values... Your both solution would require additional logic with several values btw